# Rails - Groups of resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm looking to create a resource called Products. A product has a description/price...

```
{
  description: "Cream Cheese",
  price: 1.99,
  perishable: true
}
```

That's all pretty simple, but I may have in stock 2 separate containers of "Cream Cheese" that have different expiration dates. What is the correct/best way to model a resource around these individual variables.

EDIT: Sorry, the above wasn't very clear. I'll be getting many many orders of the same Cream Cheese, with the same UPC code and price, so I'm thinking it would be good to make it a single Product. Then somehow I need to store expiration dates for individual items, maybe through a separate related resource?

Comment: I didn't understand from the question: what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: If those are two different items, will you not have two different rows in the database with the same columns?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry for the lack of clarity, see the edit above, hopefully that clears it up a bit.

Comment: @TejaKantamneni I added some extra info above, but basically I'll only have like 15 different food items, and I'll be getting in hundreds of orders for them with many different expiration dates. So it would be good to store the description/price separately from the expiration date info.

Comment: It sounds like your Products is a 'generic' external view if Cream Cheese is Cream cheese. Backing that I would expect to find something like an inventory table containing the product ID (in this case the cream cheese ID), an on-hand lot count (I have 7 packages of it), and the expiration date for that lot (with a sell by date of next Wednesday), and possibly other such 'internal' information (so you can not sell it past it's expiration date, no?).

Comment: @railsdog Like an inventory item with `expiration_date` that `belongs_to` the cream cheese?

Comment: Yeah. I presume that you could have multiple 'lots' of some products if a lot is determined by the expiration_date.  Product has_many lots, and a lot belongs to a product. The lot could contain whatever additional fields you wanted to track (perhaps your acquisition price for the lot?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are describing the problem pretty well (which is usually the hard part). Now you just have to model what you wrote. Depending on what you need to store you have many alternatives. I am proposing you one that might inspire your real case:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  # upc: string
  # string: description string
  # float: price (or integer representing cents)
  # boolean: perishable
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  # datetime: expires_at
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order

  # integer: quantity
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
end
```